# MLX90640 thermal camera subpage are shifted when the object is moving too fast

Tags: camera, firmware, datasheet

I am deploying the application with MLX90640 sensor (thermal camera 32x24 pixels)

I am facing the issue, that when the object is moving too quickly, I can see that the subpages are shifted against each other.

See the example: [image: Example of shifted data]

Is possible that there is issue on my side ? According the datasheet I am reading the subpages separately and controlling the subpage number.

[image: Subpages description]

Or is possible that the subpages are captured each in different time, what cause me this shift and I should increase the reading rate to minimize this effect ?

Thanks for any idea or help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a subpage does not have all the pixels. The sum of the two subpages results in a complete frame. When there are fast movements you will always find this problem, because each subpage has been captured at different times and the object is in another place. In the data sheet "Reading patterns" you can read the explanation and see that there are two different patterns. default chess

[chess pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzjeJ.jpg)

Some libraries allow you to read a subpage instead of the full frame, that is useful because you could interpolate the missing pixels, with the advantage of not getting the pattern, and getting "more frames per second", but you will lose definition.

edit:
Also,the refresh rate also influences, you can configure it to from 0.5hz to 64hz.